# Access to api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/following as a user

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I'm try to request call this route api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/following also getting the error :

`Authenticating with OAuth 2.0 Application-Only is forbidden for this endpoint.  Supported authentication types are [OAuth 1.0a User Context, OAuth 2.0 User Context].`

I've trying to understand how I should generate an oauth token valid for this request, but i'm a bit lost! I've all the pipe line for the user authentication and for the last request I can get all user data including userToken and tokenSecret how i can use that info to generate the token for my request?

Also I've try to generate a token generate with apiKey and apiSecret withtou success

curl -u 'apiKey:apiSecret' 
--data 'grant_type=client_credentials' 
'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token'

I'm really lost using twitter api because of the multiples ways to authenticate

Answer (score 1):

The curl command you're using will give an App-Only token, this won't work if you're trying the POST /2/users/:id/following endpoint. Follow this [guide](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/user-access-token) on generating an OAuth 2.0 User Access Token.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).