# Using tweepy to like someone's post

Tags: tweepy

I am trying to like someone's tweet but getting an error: 'Access Token must be provided for OAuth 1.0a User Context'. DIdn't I already provided the access token? THis is the code I use, thank you for your help:

```
import tweepy as tw
import config
auth = tw.OAuthHandler(config.api_key, config.api_secret)
auth.set_access_token(config.access_token, config.access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
client = tw.Client(config.bearer_token)
user = api.get_user(screen_name='nameofuser')
user_id = user.id
tweets = client.get_users_tweets(user_id, user_auth=True)
tweet_id = tweets[0][1].id
liked = client.like(tweet_id, user_auth=True)  //error here
```

My dev account at twitter is configured to read/write. Answers to similar questions did not provide any help.

Comment: Post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71299954/access-to-api-twitter-com-2-users-id-following-as-a-user may be indicate that additional code is needed if I am trying to post to a twitter. Is that right? Any example?

Answer (score 0):

`API` is used for the V1 of the API and `Client` is used for the the V2 of the API.

Your `api` is configured with your access and your secret token (OAuth 1.0a User Context) but your `client` is only configured with the bearer_token of your application (OAuth 2.0 App-Only).

So you get an error when you try to do user actions with your `client`.

Fortunately, it is easy to configure your `client` for the OAuth 1.0a User Context:

```py
client = tw.Client(
    consumer_key='...',
    consumer_secret'...',
    access_token='...',
    access_token_secret='...'
)
```

Comment: Mickaēl, I did follow your example then tried client.get_user(username='..username', user_auth=False) but still got a 401 unauthorized. True or false has no impact

Comment: The above code is a cut and paste from the tweepy docs. If you have a working example feel free to post